# If $f \in \mathcal{L}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, does it imply that it is bounded almost everywhere?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

If $f \in \mathcal{L}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, does it imply that it is bounded almost everywhere?

Comment: no, of course not.

Comment: What do you mean by bounded a.a. ? If $f(x) = \infty$ on a set with measure $>0$ (whatever that would mean), then obviously $\int f^2 = +\infty$.

Comment: @AlexHalm Maybe they mean there exists some $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for almost all $x$.

Comment: @user46944 i.e. $f\in \mathcal L^\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-1/3} & 0 < |x| < 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Note that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^2dm = 2\int_0^1x^{-2/3} = 2\left[3x^{1/3}\right]_0^1 = 6 < \infty,$$

so $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now let $M > 0$ and let $K = \sqrt[3]{M}$. Note that $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid |f(x)| > M\} = \left(-\frac{1}{K}, \frac{1}{K}\right)\setminus\{0\}$ which has positive measure. Therefore, $f$ is not bounded almost everywhere. In particular, the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my favorites, 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} n & n < x < n+\frac{1}{n^4},\, n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Then $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

while $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|^2\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$